# Swift 5: simple string URLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I hope you can help me.

I am currently using native swift apis for URLSession and URLRequest network calls.

I have achieved the correct sending of json structures with the use of dictionaries.

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["user": "demo"]
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://.....")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
  }catch _ {}
```

How would it be possible to send a simple string?

```
let params: "demo"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://.....")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = .......?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the string to a `Data`, using `data(using:)`:

```
request.httpBody = "a simple string".data(using: .utf8)
```

Comment: it is necessary to add -> request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")      ?

Comment: @esantiago Should your "simple string" be interpreted as JSON. If so, add that. If not, you should also add that, but use something like `text/plain` for the content type, rather than `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
request.httpBody = Data("yourString".utf8)
```

Comment: it is necessary to add? -> request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Comment: yes you need to guide your sever for the content sent whether its text , html , json or media in your current case its a json interpretation